# Классное видео!

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор

Комментарий к видеоролику "Классное видео!" — неполное предложение?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Это номинативная конструкция.**

Чтобы ее определить, надо исходить из **классификации** номинативных предложений. Вот у Кустовой номинативные предложения делятся **на три вида**: бытийные, указательные, оценочные.

При этом она указывает, что номинативные предложения со значением оценки в какой-то мере **противопоставлены** бытийным и указательным. Оценка в таких предложениях соотносится со сказуемым в двусоставных предложениях, а не с подлежащим, как в первых двух.

А что тогда между ними **общего**? Они не имеют парадигмы и всегда относятся к настоящему времени. **Это восприятие предмета или его оценка в момент речи.**

Кустова не использует термин *изолированный номинатив*, но эти понятия, номинативное  оценочное предложение и изолированный номинатив со значением оценки, очень близки.

***Классное видео!***  Наблюдатель дает оценку тому, что он видит в момент речи. Ему нравится содержание или профессиональная съемка — в принципе это неважно. Он мог бы видеть эту картину в действительности и сказать: красивый пейзаж!

Исходя из этих рассуждений я бы отнесла эту конструкцию к **номинативным  предложениям со значением оценки**.

В **неполном** предложении содержание восстанавливается по предыдущему тексту, а здесь текста нет. **Изолированный номинатив** тоже связан с контекстом.

Comment: Спасибо! А если рассмотреть такой случай: я задаю вопрос, и мой собеседник отвечает мне: "Дурацкий вопрос, Сережа!", то здесь неполное предложение?

Comment: Диалог - это уже наличие контекста, в этом случае это скорее неполное предложение: Это дурацкий вопрос, Сережа!

Comment: Спасибо! Вы допускаете, что этот пример (Классное видео!) тоже можно трактовать как двусоставное предложение с инверсией? Можно ли считать Красивый пейзаж! тоже двусоставным с инверсией?