# Номинативное предложение или двусоставное с инверсией?

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор

> Хороший актер!
>   Хорошая пьеса!

Возможна ли трактовка данных предложений как двусоставные предложения с инверсией сказуемого (актер - хороший!), если интонационно выделено прилагательное?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю, что грамматика предложения зависит от ситуации или контекста.

**Если это** оценочная восклицательная реплика, то ее просто нельзя произнести с другой интонацией: **логическое ударение в этом случае падает на прилагательное**, которое является именным сказуемым в двусоставном предложении.

**Дополнение**

Эта сочетание можно считать гибридным, то есть его можно отнести или как номинативным оценочным предложениям, так и к двусоставным предложениям **в разных ситуациях.**

Кустова, да и Розенталь тоже, отмечают двойственный характер  ном. оценочных предложений. Номинатив в этом случае соотносится **со сказуемым** двусоставного предложения, а не с подлежащим, как для ном. предложений другого вида.

У Кустовой есть пример ном.предложения: *Был у меня знакомый. Удивительный человек!* Здесь **ударение не переносится на прилагательное,** произношение как в обычном словосочетании.

А вот сочетание "хороший актер", вероятно, может иметь **варианты произношения**, причем с разным смыслом.

(1) ХорОший актёр! Это двусоставное предложение.

(2) Хороший актЁр! Это номинативное оценочное предложение. Здесь возможен иронический подтекст (человек умеет притворяться). Тогда получается, что в разных структурах разное ударение.

Comment: Спасибо! Пример Красивый пейзаж! и Классное видео! Вы отнесли к [номинативным оценочным предложениям](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/449915/%D0%9A%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BE/449920). Как тогда быть?

Comment: Ответьте, пожалуйста

Comment: Эта сочетание можно считать гибридным, то есть его можно отнести и к номинативным оценочным предложениям, и к двусоставным в разных ситуациях.  Кустова, да и Розенталь тоже, отмечают двойственный характер таких ном. предложений. Номинатив  в этом случае соотносится со сказуемым двусоставного предложения, а не с подлежащим, как для  ном. предложений другого вида.  У Кустовой есть пример ном.предложения: Был у меня знакомый. Удивительный человек! Здесь ударение не падает  на прилагательное. А вот сочетание "хороший актер", вероятно, может иметь варианты произношения, причем с разным смыслом.

Comment: Хороший актЁр! Здесь возможен иронический подтекст (человек умеет притворяться). Тогда получается,  что в разных структурах разное ударение.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Извините за настойчивость. Добавьте, пожалуйста, замечание о разных трактовках в ответ, чтобы его можно было закрыть, хотя это на Ваше усмотрение. Замечаний в комментариях тоже достаточно, я приму ответ в любом случае.

Comment: Красивый пейзаж! Вы тоже отнесете к гибридным сочетаниям?

Comment: Я бы не стала использовать этот термин, его в лингвистике нет. А объяснение такое. Если мы  даем оценку именно пейзажу (КрасИвый пейзаж!),  то это двусоставное предложение (ударение на первом слове).  Это может быть картина или природный пейзаж.  В другой ситуации мы какое-либо явление (положительное или отрицательное) можем назвать целым сочетанием (использовать его в качестве оценки). В этом случае словосочетание произносится без перемещения ударения. Например: Туристы оставили после себя живописную кучу разнообразного мусора. КрасИвый пейзАж, ничего не скажешь!